# Toggle onClick jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web-designing. I have this sample code which toggles a div when we click anywhere on the window.

```
<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>slide demo</title>
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
                   <style>
                     #toggle {
                     width: 100px;
                     height: 100px;
                     background: #ccc;
                     }
                   </style>
                   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">                       </script>
       </head>
       <body>

       <p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
       <div id="toggle"></div>

       <script>
          $( document ).click(function() {
          $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
          });
       </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can I add an image and change the image for show and hide? I have an '>' icon. When I click on it, div should appear and '>' should change to '<'

Comment: instead of registering the click handler to document, register it to a button

Comment: add a button with say id="btn1", then you can set click event like this: 
    $( '#btn1').click(function() {
      $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do as follow

```
<img src='source:<'  id='imageid' data-othersource='source:>' />
```

You can declare an image like that with the two sources and then switch the src in jQuery.

```
//wait for the document to be fully loaded to execute
$(document).ready(function(){
  //use event delegation
  $(document).on('click','#imageid',function(){

    var $this= $(this);
    $('#toggle').toggle('slide',function(){
      //swap src of the image on toggle is completed
      var imgsrc = $this.attr('src');
      $this.attr('src',$this.data('othersource'));
      $this.data('othersource',imgsrc)

   });
  });
});
```

This way if for some reasons, you have to change the images, you don't need to get back to script, you just need to change the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/AmqcY/

**Note**: event delegation is not necessary in this case, but still i think it's important you read about that [part](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for furthur use.

Comment: image toggled only for the first time... I want it to toggle every time div toggles

Comment: Ok i edited my post , should work now. http://jsfiddle.net/AmqcY/. But to obtain a left sliding effect like in your example you'll probably have to use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of toggle.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function () {
    $('#toggle').toggle('slide');
});
```

add a button with an unique id like this

```
<button id="buttonid">click to toggle </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of registering the click handler to document, register it to a button

if you have a button with id `mybutton` then

```
//dom ready handler so that the script is executed after the dom is loaded
jQuery(function(){
    //register the click handler to an element with id mybutton
    $('#mybutton').click(function () {
        $("#toggle").toggle("slide");
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DZn6X/)

Answer (score 0):

By id:-

```
  <button id="button_id">click to toggle </button>

   $('#button_id').click(function() {
        $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
     });
```

By class:-

```
  <button class="button_class">click to toggle </button>

     $('.button_class').click(function() {
            $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('#yourbuttonId').click(function () {
    $("#toggle").toggle("slide");
});
```

Comment: How can I add an image and change the image for show and hide?
I have an '>' icon. When I click on it, div should appear and '>' should change to '<'

Comment: you can add the image in background using css, when you click on button you can change the background positions so that respective images will come accordingly.

Comment: I want to display the image next to the div. If the div is hidden, then the image should appear to the left of the window

Comment: yes you can set the arrow position accordingly, can you make a fiddle according to your requirement

Comment: I have no idea of fiddle. Please see this demo. I want the animation on the left side.http://www.webtutorialsource.com/tutorial/show-hide-toggle-sliding-menu-css-javascript/

Comment: Done by copying source code from http://www.webtutorialsource.com/tutorial/show-hide-toggle-sliding-menu-css-javascript/  you just need to write `$(function() {
    $('#arrow').click(function() {
        if ($('#box').hasClass('hide')) {
            $('#box').attr('class', 'show');
            $('#arrow').attr('src', "/images/arrowright.png");
        } else {
            $('#box').attr('class', 'hide');
            $('#arrow').attr('src', "/images/arrowleft.png");
        }
    })
})`

Comment: only image is toggled. Not the div.

Comment: I want the menu to hide. Not slide. If it slides, then there will be an issue when the browser is re-sized

Comment: how do I make #links hidden by default and show only on click?

Comment: `$('#arrow').click(function() {
     $("#links").show();
})` and by css you can hide the links

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Syq85/)**

Try this Code

```
$('body').on('click',function(){
        $('#toggle').toggle('slide');        
    });
```